# Trying to change the color of GMSAutocompleteViewController search bar but no success till now. Can someone guide for a solution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a button, on button click, below code is getting executed.

```
- (void)addressButtonClick {
GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
acController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It opens the GMSAutocompleteViewController properly, searching is working proper, but the search bar color and the text color of search bar both are black in color. Trying to change the color of text in search bar but no success till now.

Can you please help to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution!

For Objective C

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

For Swift

```
let searchBarTextAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())]

UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes
```